# Irritating and irrelevant graphics in MSE questions

Tags: discussion, editing, images

I am looking for moral support to help me resist or give in to my temptation to delete the irritating "cute" picture from this not very interesting question ["If everyone in front of you is bald, then you're bald." Does this logically mean that the first person is bald?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669002/if-everyone-in-front-of-you-is-bald-then-youre-bald-too-does-this-logically).

Should graphics with no useful mathematical content be encouraged or discouraged?

Comment: Perhaps this should be tagged ([meta-tag:specific-question]). Well, unless this question is just an illustration and you want discuss a more general issue. (In which case this should probably be stated more clearly in the post.)

Comment: Let's not split hairs about bald persons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They should be discouraged. It's bad enough when MathJax takes a while to render, and on top of that I have to wait for some irrelevant photo or graphic to load? No thanks.

---

This is a different issue from those who don't know how to type the most basic symbols so they just take a picture with their cellphone of the textbook page, and it's also a different issue from people like me who don't know how to use TikzPlot or similar packages to draw simple straightedge and compass diagrams.

Answer (score -8):

The queue picture with stock image watermark is not even cute... and the question could use a couple more tags, as well as the un-abbreviation of "IMO". So I did that. Generally, I think it's an overkill to ask on meta about a particular edit. Draws too much attention to something that doesn't really merit it. Edits exist for a purpose, and tools for rolling back harmful edits exist as well.

I'm writing this mostly because you reminded me of the famous [Find out who's going to buy the croissants](https://web.archive.org/web/20130723152645/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807531/find-out-whos-going-to-buy-the-croissants) question on Stack Overflow, which featured [an oversized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtNqj.jpg). It caused a [lot of consternation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190106) back in the days.

Comment: So, you are telling me that if I don't know what is good or bad practice on MSE, then it is overkill for me to ask a question about it on meta MSE. So what is the purpose of meta MSE?

Comment: If we were overwhelmed by trivialities, then I'd agree with the criticism; but we're not, and I think the more general question posed in the second paragraph is useful to have, @RobArthan.

Comment: It isn’t important enough to restore the picture, but I think that removing it was humorless and a bit petty.